# How to access other embedded form fields of stencil in the Alfresco ADF component?

Tags: alfresco, stencils, stencil-component

How to access other embedded form fields of stencil in the Alfresco ADF component?
Can any one provide solution in this?

Answer (score 1):

> I got the solution to my query. I used the following code to get the
>   other fields of form:
>
> this.field.form.getFormFields();